# Starting the android zxing scanner via web app doesn't seem to work

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, web-applications, zxing

My starting point for scanning from a web app was this article [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningFromWebPages)
Then i realized it was as simple as clicking a link like this

```
http://zxing.appspot.com/scan?req=http%3A%2F%2FLOCAL_SERVER_NAME%2FMY_APP_NAME%2FMY_SERVLET%3Fcode%3D%7BCODE%7D
```

but it didn't work.

My web app is simple like this (using ajax from jquery)

```
$("#onebutton").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://zxing.appspot.com/scan",
            success:function(){
                alert("success");
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("error");
            },
            data:{
                req:"http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.100:8080%2FMY_APP_NAME%2FMY_SERVLET%3Fcode%3D%7BCODE%7D"
            }

        });
    });
```

needless to say that "#onebutton" is a button tag with that id. When Pressing such button on a browser in android it always alerts the error message. It doesn't ask for the scanner to start up.
When i click the button in a normal PC, the console says:

```
"Origin http://192.168.1.100:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin".
```

Am i doing something wrong?. Am i missing something?

Thank you all in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you fully understand purpose of link.

Try to add to

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin on server`

Or

```
$("#onebutton").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://zxing.appspot.com/scan?ret=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.100:8080%2FMY_APP_NAME%2FMY_SERVLET%3Fcode%3D%7BCODE%7D",
            success:function(){
                alert("success");
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("error");
            }

        });
    });
```

but you propably dont understand

```
<a href="zxing://scan/?ret=http%3A%2F%2Ffoo.com%2Fproducts%2F%7BCODE%7D%2Fdescription&SCAN_FORMATS=UPC_A,EAN_13"> ads </a>
```

This is serve to open zxing scanner get some code information
and replace it in the given url after it is open like

.../scan!ret=www.host.com/product_{code}.hmtl

after scan it open web browser with

http://www.host.com/product_123.html

Comment: (EDIT)
Thank you, now i get the point. I was trying to make something like this:
1.- click the link in webapp.
2.- Scan the barcode.
3.- Call the servlet within the zxing app.
4.- Return the response to the webapp.
5.- Alter the webapp.
But as you point, zxing will open the encoded url in a browser. Now i dont know if i can make the flow in those 5 points.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a link like this to open the scanner:

```
<a href="zxing://scan/?ret=http://something.com/yourpage$status={CODE}"> 
    <span>My scan</span>
</a>
```

Please, pay attention that in my example $status is a variable which takes the value of the scanned barcode. This passes the value as a parameter in the address of the page it is leading to.

I see that the thread is a bit old, but I hope this will help someone.