# pic2shop url callback in ajax. ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Could you tell me(if it is possible), how can I get decoded QR code, from pic2shop but from AJAX? I dont want to reload page, when scan is ended.

Now I use:

```
window.location.href = "pic2shop://scan?callback=http://" + location[2] + "/home/Index?qr=QR"
```

I try use:
[Starting the android zxing scanner via web app doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490290/starting-the-android-zxing-scanner-via-web-app-doesnt-seem-to-work)

but without success.

Kind Regards!

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I dont remember which solution i used to resolved the issue. But i thing that you can try to use IFrame tag, then you are reloading iframe, not whole site.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that

Comment: I think a solution similar to this is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356626/using-zxing-barcode-scanner-within-a-web-page, depends on the browser